# Is it possible to see available methods of a class in a dropdownlist for eclipse interface

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Methods are listed in package explorer, however I'm asking for a simple dropdownlist over text editor like in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (the letter O, not zero) should do the trick.

Comment: And hitting it twice will provide all of the inherited methods as well.